# Creating my own file include function

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function to include requested file. I want that function to listen if i require/require_once, include/include_once

so it would look something like

```
<?php
myFile(FILE, REQO); // REQO meaning require_once
?>
```

So far i have created function that includes file:

```
define("HEADER", "header.php");
define("FOOTER", "footer.php");

function myFile($file) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
    } else {
        die($file." does not exit");
    }
    return $file;
}
```

So when i use this function in my "template" file

```
<?php
myFile(HEADER);
echo "some text";
myFile(FOOTER);
?>
```

it works fine, but i want to extend the myFile(); function the way i described. Anyone can suggest how?

Comment: `switch/case` on your 2nd argument?

Comment: Why can't you just use a require_once ("Filename")?

Comment: Use **spl-autoload-register**. There are a many guides out there about this. It's really good to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `switch` statement.

```
define('INC', 0);
define('INCO', 1);
define('REQ', 2);
define('REQO', 3);

function myFile($file, $type = INC) {
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        switch ($type) {
            case INC: include $file; break;
            CASE INCO: include_once $file; break;
            CASE REQ: require $file; break;
            CASE REQO: require_once $file; break;
            default: die('Bad $type: ' . $type);
        }
    } else {
        die("$file does not exist");
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Then you can write:

```
myFile(HEADER, true);
```

for the "once" version.

If you really want to use a parameter `REQO`, you can do:

```
define('REQO', true);
```

Comment: This helps a lot for starters, however i want to define what myFile() does. In your case in includes. But i want function to react either it's include or require. So if i write myFile(HEADER, RQ) ir requires. If i write myFile(HEADER, INC) it includes.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use an array of the different function names to call.

Comment: Ok i try to use myFile(HEADER, INC); and i get error Call to undefined function include()

Comment: OK, apparently `include()` isn't a real function, it's PHP syntax (which I should have realized, since you can use it without parentheses around the argument). You'll have to use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is create a set of horizontal options for your function that can be turned on or off. One common way to do this is by using *bitwise* math. It's easy to flip bits on or off so that we can achieve something like `MYFILE_INCLUDE | MYFILE_ONCE` or `MYFILE_REQUIRE | MYFILE_ONCE`, for example.

Here's a simple example.

```
const MYFILE_ONCE = 1;
const MYFILE_INCLUDE = 2;
const MYFILE_REQUIRE = 4;

function myFile($file, $opt = MYFILE_INCLUDE) {
    if (($opt & MYFILE_INCLUDE) === MYFILE_INCLUDE) { // include
        if (($opt && MYFILE_ONCE) === MYFILE_ONCE) { // once
            include_once $file;
        } else {
            include $file;
        }
    } elseif (($opt & MYFILE_REQUIRE) === MYFILE_REQUIRE) { // require
        if (($opt && MYFILE_ONCE) === MYFILE_ONCE) { // once
            require_once $file;
        } else {
            require $file;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call your function like this to include a file `myfile('somefile.php', MYFILE_INCLUDE)` or like this to include once `myfile('somefile.php', MYFILE_INCLUDE | MYFILE_ONCE)`. Same with require.

## Clarification of scope

To be perfectly clear, doing `include_once` or `require_once` inside of a function is typically useless when you are using that function in attempt to replace the include/require constructs. The constructs take scope into account where they are used. So `include_once 'somefile.php'` has no effect when you call the function twice with the same file. The file is only included within the scope of that function. Once the function returns it's as if the file was never included there.

If your use case is specific and not attempting to replace include/require constructs than this might be OK, *taking this into account*, but otherwise it's not going to do what you want.

## Grain of salt warning

However, while this may seem convenient at first, I strongly advice against making this a regular practice as it is deceptively convenient. Functions should serve a single purpose. The minute you start writing a lot of functions like this it starts to look like you're function is just doing too much.

Comment: Tested this and it does not work properly. Includes twice even if i set myfile('somefile.php', MYFILE_INCLUDE | MYFILE_ONCE)

Comment: No, it works properly. It just might not do what you expect, because you're doing the include inside of a function. One of the primary reasons why the include/require constructs exist as language constructs in PHP and not as functions is specifically because they take scope into account. You may want to [refer to the documentation](http://php.net/include) about how these constructs work and why your attempt to try and replace them with custom functions is an exercise in futility.